# Autocomplete jquery not matching my json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using jquery-ui autocomplete with rails, but it doesn't work properly. It wont match results on what I put on the search, but it will rather show all of the json results (with no filter).

**In my routes**

```
get '/autocomplete-photos', to: 'photos#autocomplete'
```

**In my controller**

```
  def autocomplete
      @photos = Photo.all
      respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @photos.as_json(only: [:title, :user, :description], methods: [:avatar_url, :user, :photo_url] )}
    end
  end
```

**In my view**

```
 <%= search_form_for @spot_search, url: search_path do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_field :title_cont, id: "auto-search", :size => 15, :placeholder => "Encuentra spots..." %>
        <button type="submit" class="collapsebutton searchbutton">
        <i class="icon-magnifier"></i></button>
        <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#auto-search").autocomplete({
          source: "autocomplete-photos.json",
          minLength: 2,
          select: function(event, ui) {
             $('#auto-search').val(ui.item.photo.title);
          }
        }).data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
              var inner_html = '<a href="' + item + '"><div class="list_item_container"><div class="image"><img class="avatar_small" src="' + item.photo_url + '"></div><div class="label">' + item.title + '</div><div class="description">' + item.description + '</div></div></a>';
              return $( "<li></li>" )
                  .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                  .append(inner_html)
                  .appendTo( ul );
          };
      });
      </script>
```

Basically its working, but I don't get results on what you put on the search, but I get all of the JSON instead. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you passing a value to your controller, or is it an empty string? (giving you all of the results rather than filtered results)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it by passing in the term parameters in the controller.

```
  def autocomplete
      if params[:term]
        @photos = Photo.find(:all,:conditions => ['title LIKE ?', "#{params[:term]}%"])
      else
        @photos = Photo.all
      end
      respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @photos.as_json(only: [:title, :user, :description], methods: [:avatar_url, :user, :photo_url] )}
    end
  end
```